# What characteristics does Halcyon and Maris Otter bring to beer?

Tags: malt

I have been brewing with these two types of malts and was just wondering what types of beer are typically made with them and what taste characteristics they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maris Otter is typically used with English beers, especially "ESBs" (Extra Special Bitter). You wouldn't use it in a hoppy beer like an American IPA - the hops would crowd out the malt flavour.

It is often described as being more malty and "biscuity".

As a relative beginner, I've been using an ESB recipe taken from a kit and substituting ingredients. This latest brew (currently in the bottle - almost ready to taste) uses Maris Otter for the base malt.

November BYO had an article celebrating Maris Otter's 50th Anniversary and this includes some recipes including both a Mild and an ESB.

Comment: For what it's worth I like a strong malt profile in my IPAs to balance the bitterness so use Maris Otter for almost all of them.

Comment: Europe's upcoming craft brewery, brewdog, reportedly uses Maris on their leading brand, Punk IPA

Answer (score 1):

I have not used those two malts so far (I should very soon though), but I still managed to get some information.

#### Maris Otter:

> This malt has a lot of the bready, biscuit character that Maris Otter is famous for, though the Thomas Fawcett seems be a bit more toasty than the others. This malt is traditionally floor malted. I like using this one in my bitters and those beers that I want a lot of clean biscuit aroma and flavor. I typically won't use a lot of dark crystal and roasted malts with this one.

#### Halcyon:

> Adds a degree of biscuit flavor to the beer. Brighter and lighter in flavor than Pearl, Halcyon is a great malt for the production of Real Ales. It tends to produce a less sweet wort than Maris Otter. All the base malts from Thomas Fawcett & Sons are grown by local, family farmers near the maltings area.

Sources:

http://perfectpint.blogspot.ca/2011/03/british-malts-part-i.html

http://www.midwestsupplies.com/maillard-malts-fawcett-halcyon-pale-malt.html